# WCF : send multiple params with same name

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, get

I want to send the list of same-type items via GET to my WCF service.
For example :

```
MySite.com?MyService.svc\MyMethod?Id=1&Id=2&Id=3 .....
```

And my method

```
[OperationContract]
[WebGet(ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
public void MyMethod( ???????? )
{
 //here i want to get the list of all the id's i've sent
}
```

Or may be there is another way to send such data (i mean, 'an array' of Id's with random length

**UPD :** 
I've tried a List and string [] (anyway, it is the string yeah, but) but Exception says : 'type 'System.String[]' is not convertible by 'QueryStringConverter'.'

Comment: I've tried a List<string> and string [] (anyway, it is the string yeah, but) but Exception says : 'type 'System.String[]' is not convertible by 'QueryStringConverter'.'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to use `params` keyword. Something like:

```
public void MyMethod(params object[] list)
{
    // access by index like list[0] etc.
}
```

Instead of `object` type u can use `int` or `string` if you need.

You can read more about `params` at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w5zay9db.aspx .

Comment: Thanks, but i still have an error like ... has a query variable named 'list' of type 'System.Object[]', but type 'System.Object[]' is not convertible by 'QueryStringConverter'.

Comment: @V319 mb this topic will help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6445171/passing-an-array-to-wcf-service-via-get